# Calculation by hand different form Mathematica Simplify function

Tags: equation-solving

I look at

`ClearAll[x, y, t, q, d];
Simplify[ 0 == 1 - d x[t] - (3 + 2 d) y[t], 
 0 == 1 - d y[t] - (3 + 2 d) x[t]]`

When I solved this by hand, I found that x = y = `1/(3+3d)`

But when I put it into Mathematica, I got:

```
d x[t] + (3 + 2 d) y[t] == 1
```

Is my work by hand wrong or is my input incorrect?

Comment: Try using `Reduce[{0 == 1 - d x[t] - (3 + 2 d) y[t], 0 == 1 - d y[t] - (3 + 2 d) x[t]}, {x[t], y[t]}]` instead of `Simplify`, that gives your 'by hand' solution as one of the two possible solutions, depending on value of `d` parameter. And welcome to MMA.SE!

Comment: Thank you! I apologize in advance for my basic questions. I got `((1 + d) (3 + d) != 0 && x[t] == 1/(3 (1 + d)) && 
  y[t] == 1/3 (-1 + 6 x[t] + 3 d x[t]))` which I guess is technincally the right answer if you substitute x[t] into the equation for y[t], but it is pretty opaque

Comment: In general, it is impossible to determine 2 unknowns from 1 equation. Here, you may ask a question on what should be `x[t]` and `y[t]` so that equation is true for any values of `d`. This can be answered with the help of `SolveAlways[0==1-d x[t]-(3+2 d) y[t],{d}]`yielding `{{y[t]->1/3,x[t]->-(2/3)}}`.

Comment: I decided the OP may be interpreted as two equations (well, one equation and the second, as additional condition, also can be treated as second equation), so I advised `Reduce`. May be it is my misunderstanding of OP.